# sorting connected lists one with vote number which corresponds to a list of names

Tags: python

```
candidate_names = ['ed','dan','ollie','poppy']
votes = [10,13,8,3]
```

say I have these two lists, how can I get the code to print the person with the most votes and print their name side by side, and print there is a draw between 2-4 people with the most votes and call for a revote?
any help is much appreciated thank you :).

Comment: please some more details like the code you tried so far, expected result

Comment: currently I have been completely stuck, what I would want to happen is for this the code is that is prints-  dan got the most amount of votes with 13 votes. and if it is a tie then it prints- dan and levi tied with 15 votes. and then I recall a voting function.

Comment: then add your expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
candidate_names = ['ed','dan','ollie','poppy']
votes = [10,13,8,3]
tmp=list(zip(candidate_names,votes))#temporary list having names with votes
x=max(tmp, key=lambda x: x[1])#person with most votes
tmp.remove(x)#remove person with most votes from temp list
if(any(x[1] in y for y in tmp)):#to check for draws
    print("there was a draw")
else:
    print(x[0]," is winner")
```

to sort the list use

```
tmp.sort(key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)#person with most votes is first
```

Comment: I am quite new to python could you comment how to check for ties so I can go through the code and try understand it? thank you very much.

Comment: Made it a bit easier, Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
candidate_names = ['ed','dan','ollie','poppy']
votes = [10,13,8,3]
countvotes = votes.copy()
countvotes.sort()
if countvotes[-1] > countvotes[-2]:
    print('There was one winner')
else:
    print('There was more than one winner - Revote')

print('Most Votes received as follows')
for i in range (4):
    if votes[i] == countvotes[-1]:
        print(candidate_names[i], votes[i])
```

Countvotes sorts the list of votes. If the last number in countvotes is bigger than the second last one there was only one winner, otherwise it's a tie.

Then it prints the list with the candidates who got the most votes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is by using dictionary

```py
votes = map(float, input('Vote every member seperated by comma (,): ').split(',')) #seperate the input with ',' and convert every item into float
candidatesName = ['ed','dan', 'ollie','poppy'] #candidates
candidates = dict(zip(candidatesName, votes))# make into dict to get votes for each like if input was  10,13,9,1 then the dict would have been ed: 10, dan: 13 and blah blah
most_votes = max(candidates.values())#get the maximum votes in the case above, 13
most_voted = [i for i in candidates.keys() if candidates[i] == most_votes] #get the most voted guy
print("There is a tie between {} with {} votes".format(", ".join(most_voted), candidates[most_voted[0]])) if len(most_voted)-1 > 0 else print('{} won with {} votes'.format(most_voted[0].capitalize(), candidates[most_voted[0]])) #check if there's a tie if there are multiple items in most_voted
```

Comment: the problem I have is the info for the names and votes is user inputted so can vary.

Comment: ok, i'll edit my code for this